# RGB Colour changer form refreshes after half a secod

Tags: javascript, background, rgb

My code is supposed to change the background when a user enters RGB color codes in the three boxes provided (R, G, B) and then presses the submit button.

It does do this, but it seems to refresh after half a second removing what was there.

I need it to stay there until a user manually changes it or refreshes the page.

https://jsbin.com/kutatesesi/edit?html,js,output

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `<form onsubmit="validateRGB(); return false;">` if you're using the submit event to trigger a function then you need to invalidate the form submission by returning false to stop the browser redirecting the page.

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I would change from a submit to a click handler. I edited your jsbin. Check it out here. https://jsbin.com/kogaqafufu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You should probably re-write so your function isn't called from form submission, since you don't actually want to submit the form. However, a quick fix is to stop the form submission as soon as you have run your validateRGB function. e.g.

onsubmit="validateRGB();return false;"